# Calling a function with a replacement of listview

Tags: android, function, listview

I need to a call a function from two different classes of my code. One is a `Adapter` class where I need to call the function with `ListView` as a parameter to call the function in different class. Other is an `Activity` where I don't have this `ListView`.

Here's an example of my situation:-

```
callAFunction(listview, integer);   // calling from adapter where there is a listview

callAFunction(null, integer);    // calling from a activity where there is no listview
```

Here in this case, eclipse doesn't allow me to use this `null` parameter instead of this `ListView`. Can anyone please help explain how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you make `callAFunction` yourself?

Comment: Why not pass it something like -1?

Comment: @KristyWelsh -1 or 0 doesn't work here...

Comment: And `NULL` ? Does it make a difference?

Comment: If you made the function yourself, why not rewrite to handle a non-null value?

Comment: can you post the function?